# How to use attributes in JUnit Tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, attributes, installation

I have been working with JUnit for several years and I have found many examples where isolation within the test was not fullfil.

Most of the tests I develop follow the same structure

```
class ClassToTestTest {

    // Attributes
    private ClassToTest objectToTest;

    // Methods
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        objectToTest = new ClassToTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        //do something
        Assert...
    }

    @Test 
    public void test2() {
        //do something
        Assert...
    }
}
```

The internal state of the test object (not the ClassToTest object but the object which perform the test) are in its attributes. If there is any flaw at the setup() or teardown() methods some internal state of objectToTest might sneak to other test.

Just wondering, would it be better to have no shared state? you have no attributes

```
class ClassToTestTest {

    // Attributes
    // No attributes, no internal state

    // Methods
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        objectToTest = new ClassToTest();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        localObjectToTest = createObjectToTest();
        //do something
        Assert...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        localObjectToTest = createObjectToTest();
        //do something
        Assert...
    }
}
```

I know the first code do pretty much the same than the second, but in the first code you are tempted to do something like

```
// Methods
@Before
public void setup() {
    objectToTest = objectToTest.reset();
}
```

or even worse, rely on the previous test in order to use the state of the objectToTest in the previous test to "save" time and you end up with an empty setup() method

Following the second code is much dificult to reach this point because there is no shared state, every object is local.

What are your thoughts? Make sense? Is it worthy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JUnit creates a new `ClassToTestTest` object for each of your test methods. Therefore no field can sneak to another test. For details: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/JunitNewInstance.html

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that. Thanks, pretty informative.

It's seems TestNG don't do that. Good to know as well.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion I think it is worthy to create a `ClassToTestTest` object **in each test** because it is possible to modify the internal state and **each test should be independent of the other ones**.

A fussier developer could tell you that **you are also testing the Constructor of the object** in each test. Then, you can also use the @Before and @After annotations in the methods for creating and destroying the `ClassToTestTest` object.

But anyway, I would rather go to create the object in each test.

Edit: Adding bold font to put the text more readable